# Trace norm of matrices in SU(2)

Tags: group-theory, quantum-computation

[This thesis](https://cba.mit.edu/docs/theses/01.05.aram.pdf#page=24) states

> ... the $L^2$ or *trace norm*, [is] defined to be $||M|| = Tr \sqrt{M M^\dagger}$. If elements of SU(2) are associated with points on the surface of the 3-sphere, then this is simply equivalent to twice the Euclidean distance.

I have two points of confusion. The first is the definition of $L^2$ when applied to elements of SU(2). I have read ([here for instance](https://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/140398/1/TFG-Lumbreras-Zarapico-Josep.pdf#page=18)) that for normal matrices, this is equivalent to the sum of the eigenvalues of $M$. But for SU(2), because we have unitary matrices, does this not become $Tr \sqrt{M M^\dagger} = Tr \sqrt{I_2}  = Tr(I_2) = 2$? Is it the case that all of the trace norms of matrices in SU(2) are then equal? This doesn't seem to match up with my calculation below using eigenvalues, so I assume I have made a mistake somewhere.

Putting that aside for a moment, I seem to be able to calculate the eigenvalues of an arbitrary matrix in SU(2). After a bit of calculation, the characteristic polynomial can be written as

$$
\lambda^2 - 2 \Re(z) \lambda + 1
$$

where $z$ is the parameter along the main diagonal. This gives the eigenvalues $\Re(z) \pm  \sqrt{ \Re(z)^2 - 1 }$, and seems to match up with a couple of manual calculations I did for particular matrices. My questions:

- Is it correct that the trace norm is then $\sum \left( \Re(z) \pm  \sqrt{ \Re(z)^2 - 1 } \right) = 2 \Re(z)$?
- This seems suspect, because if I view elements of SU(2) as unit quaternions, these eigenvalues are in terms of just the real part. If correct, is there some intuition about why this is the case?
- If correct, is this enough to show the claim above about Euclidean distance? I'm not seeing the connection immediately

**Edit**:

On a second look, I think that the expression in the first bullet should be sum of the *norms* of the eigenvalues:

$$
\sum \left | \Re(z) \pm  \sqrt{ \Re(z)^2 - 1 } \right | = 2 \left | \Re(z) \pm  \sqrt{ \Re(z)^2 - 1 } \right |
$$

which gives me the expected trace norm of 2 for the few SU(2) matrices I checked by hand. So the calculation makes sense, though the intuition of the 3-sphere and interpretation as a function of the real component of a quaternion is still unintuitive to me.

Comment: Most of what you write is correct, except the first bullet point: the trace norm is the trace of the square root of $MM^\dagger$ and is one when $M\in SU(2)\,.$ The sum of the eigenvalues is however the trace of $M\,.$

Comment: Typo on my side. If the "trace norm" is what that article says then it is two not one. However, I am unable to link this "trace norm" to any other norm we find in the internet:  [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm): $\|M\|_F=\sqrt{\text{Tr}(MM^\dagger)}\,.$ In your case this is $\sqrt{2}\,.$ [$L_2$ or spectral norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_p-norms): $\|M\|_2=\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(MM^\dagger)}\,.$ In your case this is one.

Comment: I believe this norm corresponds to the [Schatten norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms) with $p = 1$.

Comment: Looks right! Welcome to the zoo of matrix norms. Apparently this Schatten norm is also called ***nuclear norm*** and Ky Fan $n$-norm.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence in the edit: forget about the norms for a moment. Use a bit of linear algebra to see that each matrix in $SU(2)$ (unitary with determinant one) is described by four real parameters that must satisfy $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1\,.$ There you have the three sphere. All three norms (Frobenius, spectral, Schatten) we considered above are constant on that sphere. That's imho all.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Whatever norm we pick differs by a constant multiple, so it's not necessary that there's a special connection between the Schatten and Euclidean norms. (Maybe a bit of a non sequitur in the text). The parameterization of the norm is still interesting though, but maybe doesn't extend to SU(n) generally.

Comment: Welcome to the zoo of special unitary groups. Afaik $SU(2)$ is the only one that has such nice Euclidean properties. It is also identical to the unit quaternions.